# Can any one point me to some resource that explain pallet_democracy?

Tags: pallet-democracy

I have a requirement, such that, any person will submit a proposal that will be voted by other members and if the majority votes are achieved, the proposal will be executed.

For this purpose, I am considering to use pallet_democracy. Can any body point me to some resource/guide that explains pallet_democracy in detail. As the documentation of the democracy pallet is not enough to grasp full concept of democracy pallet

Comment: Please keep your questions specific, we are not here to help you surf the web ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, always check the official wiki first.

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-democracy

Answer (score 1):

Moonbeam has resources you can take a look at: https://docs.moonbeam.network/builders/pallets-precompiles/pallets/democracy/

Comment: Thanks for info

Answer (score 1):

Syed, have you watched the Friday Polkadot [Deep Dive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgcUWK2E9Jo) on pallet-democracy? It's one of the best resources to dive into such topics.

Comment: Let me watch that. Thanks @Lana