# How to modify democracy pallet to burn tokens?

Tags: pallet-democracy

In democracy pallet, user has to stack some token to put forward a proposal or to vote in favour of or against a proposal. How I can change this behaviour such that, some or all the tokens stacked by the user are burned instead of stacked?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't stuck. It has just been locked.

Users can easily unlock it by:

[image]

---

Why do you want to burn the token? I don't that's a good idea.

Comment: Is it technically possibel?

Comment: Yes, that is its design. Check this also https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-democracy.

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8162/can-any-one-point-me-to-some-resource-that-explain-pallet-democracy/8171#8171

Answer (score 1):

Technically it can be done, there might be other options but I show you two:

- In the you can [Config](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L235) of the `pallet_democracy` you can specify your own Currency type for this pallet:

```rs
type Currency: ReservableCurrency<Self::AccountId>
            + LockableCurrency<Self::AccountId, Moment = Self::BlockNumber>;
```

And implement your traits ReservableCurrency and LockableCurrency to make them burn the tokens instead of reserve them.

The node-template for example is using in its [Config](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L949) a trait defined in the FRAME Support pallet. You can see the implementation of this traits [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/currency).

- The second option is modify the pallet itself for your own use case.

In the [function](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L1274) where is doing the vote `try_vote`, you can instead of lock the currency, burn it. (See this [previous answer on Stackexchange](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/8177/2762)).
Or keep the reserve token logic, and when you want to burn it Slash it with `T::Currency::slash_reserved`.

This is how it can be implemented in your pallet, but as the comment from AurevoirXavier is hard to see a use case where it makes sense to burn the tokens in a vote.